# Why half of total unit test cases are skipped?

Tags: automated-tests, vstest

We have two controllers to execute the same unit test, but get different result. I have no idea what is the reason.

Controller1: half number of unit test cases skipped

1. Output: Assembly unitTest.dll failed. Total: 836, Passed: 418, Failed: 0, Other: 418 Click here for details
2. output result cleanupScript.log show that TotalAgents=2

Controller2: all unit test cases succeed

1. Output: Assembly unitTest.dll Passed . Total: 836, Passed: 836, Passed: 0, Other: 0 Click here for details
2. output result cleanupScript.log show that TotalAgents=1

Question: why unitTest.dll in controller1 is allocated to two agents? and why half number of the test cases in controller1 are skipped? Is virtual machine have connection with test agent allocation?

[image: Test Controller & Agents image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Bucket size and MinimumTestsPerAgent setting in controller’s configuration file (QTController.exe.config, in VS installation path)

Some article:

[How to: Run Automated Tests on Multiple Computers at the Same Time From a Test Plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff950318(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to run automated tests on different machines in parallel?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2010/08/11/how-to-run-automated-tests-on-different-machines-in-parallel/)